# how to make disabled input button not ‘grey’ in ios browser?

Tags: html, ios, css, web

html
 (input type button disabled), on IPhone devices it's grey!
but I want it stay in the same style when it's disabled...
how to do that?

I tried use “-webkit-appearance: none;” 
all (input type button) changed to my css,
but the disabled buttons is still grey...
even if I write "input:disabled{background-color:white}"

```
<style>
input{
    display: block;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin:5px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: white;
}

input:disabled{
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: white;
    }
</style>
<body>
<input id="button1" type="button" disabled>

</body>
```

I want IPhone use the style I write...
on IPhone,https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj071.jpg
on PC/Android,https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXJhv.jpg

Comment: `button:disabled, button[disabled] { background: #fff !important; -webkit-appearance: none;}` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!!

just **set opacity to 1**

```
input:disabled {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to get the disabled button to stay white?  It might help for you to use the following string:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
   background-color: white !important;
}
```

The important tag will force the background to be white.

Comment: not work..disabled input button is still grey on **IPhone**... thanks anyway